# adding xprofile for this user

Tags: buddypress

the code I am created that makes the users register and auto login.
My difficulty is in adding xprofile for this user. Could you help me?

```
add_action('quform_post_process_7','register', 10, 2);
function register ($result, $form) {
    $username = $form->getValueText( 'quform_7_6' );
    $email    = $form->getValueText( 'quform_7_6' );
    $password = $form->getValueText( 'quform_7_7' );
    $role = 'shop_manager';
    $userId =  wp_insert_user(array(
        'user_login' => $username,
        'user_pass' => $password,
        'user_email' => $email,
        'role' => $role,
    ));

    $hash = wp_hash_password($password);
    update_user_meta( $user_id, '_is_shop_manager', 1 );
    update_user_meta($userId, 'nickname', $form->getValueText('quform_7_28'));
    update_user_meta($userId, 'first_name', $form->getValueText('quform_7_28'));

    if(!is_wp_error( $userId)){

        wp_set_current_user( $userId); // set the current wp user
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $userId); // startthe cookie for the current registered user

        if (bp_is_active('xprofile')) {

            if (!empty($usermeta['1,43,44'])) {

                $profile_field_ids = explode(',', $usermeta['1,43,44']);

                foreach ((array) $profile_field_ids as $field_id) {
                    if (empty($usermeta["field_1"])) {
                         $usermeta = array(
                            'field_1' => $form->getValueText('quform_7_28'),
                            'field_43' => $form->getValueText( 'quform_7_6' ),
                            'field_44' => $form->getValueText('quform_7_20'),

                        );
                     }
                    $current_field = $usermeta["field_1"];
                    xprofile_set_field_data($field_id, $user_id, $current_field);

                } 
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that the xprofile field id is the same as the user meta field id - if they are, it is just a coincidence. 
If you have not created xprofile fields, you need to do so. 
And then use the ids for those xprofile fields. 
Or you can use *the name of the xprofile field*

http://hookr.io/functions/xprofile_set_field_data/